# How to pass a variable declared as `def` inside Jenkins-groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I was trying to pass the variable `sampleArray` to `groovyScript` function of `activeChoiceReactiveParam` unfortunately the xml generated doesn't pick the values. I tried on this playground http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com as well as with real Jenkins and it wasn't working out. What I meant is the `sampleArray`'s value is not getting copied. Please tell me how this can be achieved

```
job("try-to-pass-array") {
    def sampleArray = ["one","two","three","four"]
    description("this is to test a element type")
    keepDependencies(false)
    parameters {
        activeChoiceReactiveParam('NUMBERS') {
            description('Choose numbers for which build has to be generated')
            choiceType('MULTI_SELECT')
            groovyScript {
                script('return $sampleArray')
                fallbackScript('"fallback choice"')
            }
        }
    }
    disabled(false)
    concurrentBuild(false)
    steps {
        shell('''
              echo $NUMBERS
              ''')
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use double quotes instead of single `script("return $sampleArray")`

Comment: thanks - I lost two hours sorting this out - SO rocks

Comment: as a best practice it should be withing curly braces as mentioned by mkemmerz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct string interpolation. The [jenkins (declarative pipeline) documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation) has a very good example for this.

```
def username = 'Jenkins'
echo 'Hello Mr. ${username}'
echo "I said, Hello Mr. ${username}"
```

Would result in:

```
Hello Mr. ${username}
I said, Hello Mr. Jenkins
```

so if you want to pass the values of variables always use `"` and NOT `'`.

**tl;dr** `script("return ${sampleArray}")`

Comment: very descriptive - Thanks !